# WTF error C#: 'Semestralwork.Teleport' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 argument; Teleport has 2 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

"funny" thing happened:
Note: Vector3 is struct 3xfloat coordinates x,y,z

```
class Teleport {

        Vector3 currentPosition;
        Vector3 destinationPosition;

        Teleport(Vector3 currentPosition, Vector3 destinationPosition) 
        {
            this.currentPositon = currentPositon;
            this.destinationPosition = destinationPosition;

            //...
        }
}
```

When I cast this code from another class, here we have a problem:
Note: arrays teleportPositions and destinationPositions are type Vector3[]
and they're not empty

```
Teleport[] teleportList = new Teleport[NUMBER_OF_TELEPORTS]

 for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TELEPORTS; i++) 
            {
                Vector3 actual = teleportPositons[i];
                Vector3 dest = destinatonPositions[i];
                teleportList[i] = new Teleport(actual,dest); //there is the problem
            }
```

**Visual studio says:**'Semestralwork.Teleport' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 argument.
Semestralwork is a namespace, all classes are in this namespace.

I don´t understand it but I thing I can still count to two :/

Does anyone now?
Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a word missing in the error:  'Semestralwork.Teleport' does not contain ___?___ that takes 2 argument.  Or does the error really say that?

Comment: Thanks. There was "a constructor" missing. Sry, to much work, not enough sleep.
Question edited to be correct and now also already solved :)
gn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default access modifier for the constructor is listing it as private, which means it can only be accessed from within the `Teleport` class. You want it to be `public` (or `internal` which it essentially would be based on the class' access modifier defaulting to `internal`), as follows:

```
class Teleport {
    public Teleport(Vector3 currentPosition, Vector3 destinationPosition) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I didn't see it :D 5:32 at night - time to sleep for a while. I'm glad I've removed this stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think your problem is this line:

```
Vector3 teleportList = new Teleport[NUMBER_OF_TELEPORTS]
```

You are created a variable called `teleportList` of type `Vector3`, and you trying to instantiate it as an array of `Teleport` objects.

Shouldn't it be:

```
Teleport[] teleportList = new Teleport[NUMBER_OF_TELEPORTS];
```

Comment: Sry, my bad .. i translated my code and rewrited here and I made a mystake .. I'll edit my question, I have teleportList ofcourse type Teleport[] as you mentioned .. so this isn't a problem ...

Comment: Please be sure your code is copied _verbatim_ and not "translated" so the error can be discovered.   Even the smallest syntax difference (for example, are you dereferencing both arrays with [i]?) can be overlooked easily.